# Regular expression for numbers and units

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, match

I have an dynamic string with for numbers and a unit.

The unit can be changed to cm, %, ... but it is always the same for all 4 numbers. like *"10px 12px 14px 16px"* not *"10px 12% 14cm 16in"*

I need a reqular expression to give me a result like below:

```
string = "10px 12px 14px 16px" 
result = array = [ "10 12 14 16", "px" ]
```

Consider the reqular expression should match any unit not the only mentioned above.

I have tried this but no luck:

```
var string = "10px 11px 13px 14px";
var match = string.match(/([0-9]+)(.*)/);
result: Array [ "10px 11px 13px 14px", "10", "px 11px 13px 14px" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your Regex - you can use `.split` which splits a string into arrays and then `pop` to get the last value:

```
var str =  "10px 12px 14px 16px" ;
var units =  str.split(/[0-9]+/g).pop(); // pop to get the last value
var nums = str.split(" ").map(function(x){ return parseInt(x, 10); }).join(" ");
var result = [nums, units];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks, it results in array = [ "10px 12px 14px 16px", "px" ] not array = [ "10 12 14 16", "px" ]

Comment: @user3631047 Didn't notice, fixed.

Comment: Still gives with the "px".

Comment: Oh, now it gives `["10px 12px 14px 16px", "10 12 14 16"]`.

Comment: @Scimonster lol, sorry about that - I replaced units with str and not nums :)

Comment: Thanks it is working. I have a off topic question about these answers licences. I am going to use your answer in a plugin, should I link from that plugin to this answer. Consider that it is a really tiny part of that. please answer

Comment: Technically you should but honestly I don't care.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
result = [string.match(/\d+/g).join(' '), string.match(/[a-zA-Z%]+/g).pop()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first identify the units:

```
var unit = string.match(/\d+(\S+)/).pop()
```

Then, you could remove them from the string, and put an array together:

```
result = [string.replace(new RegExp(unit,'g'),''), unit]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use back-references to check that all the units are the same:

```
s = /^(-?[0-9]+)([^ ]*) *(-?[0-9]+)\2 *(-?[0-9]+)\2 *(-?[0-9]+)\2$/.exec(x);
if (s) {
    result = [s[1], s[3], s[4], s[5], s[2]];
    ...
} else {
   // No match (e.g. units are different)
}
```

Comment: @user3631047: That won't detect if you pass `"10px 2cm 6em 3%"`

Comment: yes, but in my code it is only possible to select one unit. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

if you allow yourself to make these very safe assumptions:

1. all unit designators are made up of non-numbers (cm, px, pt, %)
2. all values are made up of numbers (10, 12, 14, 16)

this regex will get your values:

```
string.match(/(\d+)/g);
```

and this will get your unit:

```
string.match(/\D+$/);
```

and you can combined them:

```
string.match(/(\d+)|\D+$/g);
```